# detect which plane is tapped on arkit

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I am working with ARKit and I have several planeNodes (SCNPlanes) in a scene. I would like to use a hittest to detect touches on the plane, but I'm unsure on how to detect which plane was tapped on. Each plane has a name associated with it from my image recognition code. Here is my TouchesBegan function:

```
//detects taps on transparent planes created by reference images
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        if(touch.view == self.sceneView){
            let viewTouchLocation:CGPoint = touch.location(in: sceneView)
            guard let result = sceneView.hitTest(viewTouchLocation, options: nil).first else {
                return
            }
            print("results", "\(result)")
            let touchPlaneNode = planeNode
            if touchPlaneNode == result.node {
                print("tapped on a match, but which plane did I tap on?")
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I have read your question correctly, a good way to start is to store the ARPlaneAnchor and it's associated SCNNode in a dictionary e.g:

```
    var planes = [ARPlaneAnchor: PlaneNode]()
```

The 'Plane Node' value in my case is a custom SCNNode, but you can store whichever node you like.

This reference would then be created in the following ARSCNView Delegate Method:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check The We Have An ARPlane Anchor
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

        //2. Create Our Plane Node
        let planeNode = PlaneNode(anchor: planeAnchor, node: node, image: true, identifier: planes.keys.count, opacity: 1)

        //3. Store A Reference To It
        planes[planeAnchor] = planeNode


}
```

Then in Touches Began you can do something like this:

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    /*
     1. Get The Current Touch Location
     2. Check That We Have Touched A Valid Node
     3. Check That Our Touched Object Is An ARPlane Anchor
     4. Determine If It Is One That Has Been Stored
     5. Get It's Name
     */

    guard let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: augmentedRealityView),
        let hitTest = augmentedRealityView.hitTest(touchLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent).first,
        let planeAnchor = hitTest.anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor,
        let detectedPlane = self.planes[planeAnchor],
        let nodeID = detectedPlane.name
        else {
             //No Valid Plane Has Been Detected
            return

    }

    print(nodeID)


}
```

In the touchesBegan method, augmentedRealityView refers to an ARSCNView set up as an IBOutlet.

My PlaneNode Class looks like this (you will need to add your own image which in my Assets Bundle is called: defaultGrid):

```
class PlaneNode: SCNNode {

let DEFAULT_IMAGE: String = "defaultGrid"
let NAME: String = "PlaneNode"
var planeGeometry: SCNPlane
var planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor

var widthInfo: String!
var heightInfo: String!
var alignmentInfo: String!

//---------------
//MARK: LifeCycle
//---------------

/// Inititialization
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - anchor: ARPlaneAnchor
///   - node: SCNNode
///   - node: Bool
init(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, node: SCNNode, image: Bool, identifier: Int, opacity: CGFloat = 0.25){

    self.planeAnchor = anchor

    self.planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(anchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)

    super.init()

    if image{

        let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: DEFAULT_IMAGE)

        self.planeGeometry.materials = [planeMaterial]
    }

    planeNode.simdPosition = float3(self.planeAnchor.center.x, 0, self.planeAnchor.center.z)
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    planeNode.opacity = opacity

    node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    node.name = "\(NAME) \(identifier)"

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

deinit {
    #if DEBUG
    print("Plane Node Deinitialized")
    #endif
}

/// Updates The Size Of The Plane As & When The ARPlaneAnchor Has Been Updated
///
/// - Parameter anchor: ARPlaneAnchor
func update(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {

    self.planeAnchor = anchor

    self.planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
    self.planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)

    self.position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.center.x, 0.01, anchor.center.z)

    returnPlaneInfo()
}

//-----------------------
//MARK: Plane Information
//-----------------------

/// Returns The Size Of The ARPlaneAnchor & Its Alignment
func returnPlaneInfo(){

    let widthOfPlane = self.planeAnchor.extent.x
    let heightOfPlane = self.planeAnchor.extent.z

    var planeAlignment: String!

    switch planeAnchor.alignment {

    case .horizontal:
        planeAlignment = "Horizontal"
    case .vertical:
        planeAlignment = "Vertical"
    }

    #if DEBUG
    print("""
        Width Of Plane =  \(String(format: "%.2fm", widthOfPlane))
        Height Of Plane =  \(String(format: "%.2fm", heightOfPlane))
        Plane Alignment = \(planeAlignment)
        """)
    #endif

    self.widthInfo = String(format: "%.2fm", widthOfPlane)
    self.heightInfo = String(format: "%.2fm", heightOfPlane)
    self.alignmentInfo = planeAlignment
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey Josh thanks for the tip! I'm getting an error on the top line where I define planes: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` Any ideas?

Comment: What's your PlaneNode class look like?

Comment: Also, whenever you get a second. I'm getting this error in the console:

`When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.`

This only started happening after making the changes based on your code. Any idea what this error could be referring to? Thanks again!

Comment: This is talking about something within Interface builder, or the way you are setting up your scene. When I run it, I don't get any issues in the console :)

Comment: Okay thanks for narrowing it down. I'll take another look at my code. Thanks Josh!